# Problem with Regex to validate on streetNumber

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a streetNumber. It has to be a maximum of 4 in length and first 3 should be a number and the last can be a letter( no special character allowed). The letter is not compulsory.
Example 2, 34A, 45, 101 or 121B are all possible numbers. I have this regex but it is not working for me. Can anyone help me.

`^[1-9]|[A-Za-z]{1,4}`

I expect `2`, `34A`, `45`, `101` or `121B` to all pass the regex check

Comment: As a side note, be sure to read [this article](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) about addresses.

Comment: I guess one more requirement is that it doesn't start with a zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[1-9]\d{0,2}[A-Za-z]?$`

### Explanation:

- `[1-9]` a digit between 1 and 9.
- `\d{0,2}` zero or more (up to 2) digits.
- `[A-Za-z]?` a letter (optional)

https://regexr.com/4br78

In case you want to allow 4 digit numbers:
`^[1-9]\d{0,2}[A-Za-z\d]?$`

Comment: I'd add `^...$` since this is for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `^[1-9]\d{0,2}[A-Z]?$`

Explanation:

`^` - beginning of the string

`[1-9]` - match 1 through 9

`\d{0,2}` - match zero to two digits

`[A-Z]?` - match zero or one letter

`$` - end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAENbl/2)

Comment: With this regex numbers can start with a zero.

Comment: @Marlaqk OP didn't specify that this is invalid

Comment: This disallows any single digit house number

Comment: This doesn't accept lower case letters and 4 digits.

Comment: @Oram Your solution doesn't allow 4 digits either.

Comment: @Oram Lowercase letters were not specified in question and 4 digits would be matched. See the demo

Comment: I meant, his does allow it while he shouldn't.

Comment: I think it should

Comment: Who says it shouldn't? *"It has to be a maximum of 4 in length and first 3 should be a number and the last can be a letter [...]"* This implies that the 4th one can also be a number.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, sorry I did not include that edge case in my question but the 4th cannot be a number ,since we do not have streetNumbers in 1000s in my use case. So It can be 1-3 numbers maximum and if there should be a 4th , then it should be only a single character.